# want to give separate link to comma seperated string in an array

Tags: php, href

I have the following table :

[image]

In the query I have used group_concat to take the bug id's.
I want to give separate link to each bug id.
for eg : link to be given is 
    "show_bug.cgi?id =3743200"

following is the code, I have used :

```
 $query = "select count(cbm.bug_id) as count,(select     concat(round((count(cbm.bug_id)/(select count(*) from techzilla.category_bug_map cbm,techzilla.bugs b where b.assigned_to =$userId  and cbm.bug_id=b.bug_id) * 100 ),2),'%')) as Percentage ,group_concat(b.bug_id separator ',') as BugIds from techzilla.bugs b left join techzilla.category_bug_map cbm on cbm.bug_id = b.bug_id where b.assigned_to = $userId and b.creation_ts >= '$fromDate 00:00:00' and b.creation_ts <= '$toDate 00:00:00' and cbm.os IN ('$opess')";
   $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Bad query: " . mysql_error() );
   while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
   echo "<tr><td>$opess</td>
            <td>$row[0]</td>
            <td>$row[1]</td>
            <td>$row[2]</td></tr>";

   }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you post for result set using var_dump().
it will help to answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

```
$ids = explode(',', $bugs);
foreach($bugs as $b) {
    echo '<a href="...">'.$b.'</a>';  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$bugIdString="3743121,3743125,3743126,3743193";

$bugIdArray=explode(",",$bugIdString);

foreach($bugIdArray as $bug_id){
    echo "<a href='show_bug.cgi?id=$bug_id'>$bug_id</a>, ";
}
```

Comment: @Jenifer_justin did I answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Try use the code from this example:

```
// here gets //selects the row with BUG IDs
$bug_id = '3743200,3743234,3743212';
$arrids = explode(',', $bug_id);
$links = '';
for($i=0; $i<count($arrids); $i++) {
  $links .= '<br/><a href="show_bug.cgi?id='.trim($arrids[$i]).'">'.$arrids[$i].'</a>';
}
echo $links;
```